# How to write a SQL query multiple rows from the input table into one row in the output table

Tags: sql

Please find the below query. And Suggest me

```
select N_EPD_CORE_BNK_TRANS_ID,
case  
  when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='RM' 
  then  X_ASSIGN_STAGE
  end RM_stage,
  case  
  when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='RM' 
  then X_ACTION
  end RM_action,
  case  
  when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='CO' 
  then  X_ASSIGN_STAGE
  end CO_stage,
  case  
  when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='CO' 
  then X_ACTION
  end CO_action,
  Case  
  when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='CREDITREP' 
  then  X_ASSIGN_STAGE
  end CR_stage,
  Case  
  when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='CREDITREP' 
  then  X_ACTION
  End Cr_Action
  From  Rmwb_Epd_Action_Details_F Where N_Epd_Core_Bnk_Trans_Id='475';
```

The above query resulting as below in three rows by N_Epd_Core_Bnk_Trans_Id same ID

```
 475   null    null     CO      Escalate       null            null
 475   RM      Note     null    null           null            null
 475   null    null     null    null           CREDITREP       Escalate
```

But I am trying to get as below in single record. If  it is  possible, Please suggest me.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
475     RM  Note    CO  Escalate    CREDITREP   Escalate
```

Comment: Do you want a single row as your result? Your desired result seems to have values from different rows. If that being the case, what is your selection criteria?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   N_EPD_CORE_BNK_TRANS_ID,
    MAX(case  
      when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='RM' 
      then  X_ASSIGN_STAGE
      end) RM_stage,
    MAX(  case  
      when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='RM' 
      then X_ACTION
      end) RM_action,
    MAX(  case  
      when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='CO' 
      then  X_ASSIGN_STAGE
      end) CO_stage,
    MAX(  case  
      when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='CO' 
      then X_ACTION
      end) CO_action,
    MAX(  Case  
      when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='CREDITREP' 
      then  X_ASSIGN_STAGE
      end) CR_stage,
    MAX(  Case  
      when X_ASSIGN_STAGE='CREDITREP' 
      then  X_ACTION
      End )Cr_Action
      From  Rmwb_Epd_Action_Details_F Where N_Epd_Core_Bnk_Trans_Id='475'
    group by N_Epd_Core_Bnk_Trans_Id;
```